# Understanding unit Testing in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I'm a grails beginner. and was trying to understand the unit test ..
when i create a domain class `Author` grails automatically creates a test controller `AuthorControllerTests` for that domain.

so . in test controller the second line is @Mock(Author)

what does that mean.. what is the advantage i get when i mock a domain class?

Answer (score 1):

as it says in the [extensive documentation on testing](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html):

> The Mock annotation creates mock version of any collaborators. There is an in-memory implementation of GORM that will simulate most interactions with the GORM API. For those interactions that are not automatically mocked you can use the built in support for defining mocks and stubs programmatically.

Also AuthorControllerTests are the tests for the AuthorController, not the Author domain class.

Comment: So u mean to say that the methods written in Author domain cannot be tested with this AuthorControllerTests  class? i need to create separate testClass for Author domain class ?

Comment: You could do, but then you might have another controller that uses Author, are you going to test the domain there too? If you keep it separate [and test your domain object with a domain test](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains) and your [controller with a controller test](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers), you'll avoid repeating yourself, and get code that's easier to find

Answer (score 1):

Just to add something, mocking is useful when you need to isolate a "unit" of code like here your controller.

By isolating, we mean write simple components to replate and simulate all dependancies. This simple components are what we call Mocks.

Grails here gives you the possibility to mock the domain class which will make your tests easier as it won't store the information in the database.

If you want to test the whole stack, from the controller to the database, it's what we call an integration test.

hope it helps